# Bar chart not showing data using Chart.js with CSV to JSON conversion

Tags: javascript, json, csv, chart.js, visualization

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm facing an issue with generating a bar chart using Chart.js after converting CSV data to JSON. Despite successfully loading and converting the CSV data, the bar chart doesn't display any bars.

I'm currently working on a web project that involves uploading a CSV file, converting its contents to JSON, and then visualizing the data in a bar chart using Chart.js. The process seems to work fine up to the point of converting the CSV data to JSON, as I've validated the JSON output and confirmed that the data is present.

Steps I've Taken:

Created an HTML file with a file input element (fileInput) to upload a CSV file.
Implemented a JavaScript function (handleFile()) to handle the file input and perform CSV to JSON conversion using a custom csvToJson() function.
Displayed the JSON data in an HTML table using displayTable() function, and it appears correctly in the table.
Utilized Chart.js to generate a bar chart in the generateVisualization() function. The chart creation seems to work without errors, but the bars are not visible.
Expected Behavior:

After selecting a CSV file and clicking the "Convert and Save as JSON" button, the code should display the data in the HTML table and generate a bar chart based on the JSON data using Chart.js. The bar chart should show bars representing the popularity data.

```js
function generateVisualization(data) {
  const labels = data.map((item) => item.Language);
  const popularityData = data.map((item) => parseInt(item.Popularity));

  const ctx = document.createElement("canvas");
  ctx.setAttribute("id", "popularityChart");
  ctx.setAttribute("width", "400");
  ctx.setAttribute("height", "200");

  const chartContainer = document.getElementById("chartContainer");
  chartContainer.innerHTML = "";
  chartContainer.appendChild(ctx);

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Popularity",
          data: popularityData,
          backgroundColor: "#007bff",
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the `data` value to reproduce the issue? Thanks.

Comment: This chart works, [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2qwo7kt/) (despite the fact that setting canvas width and height attributes doesn't have the effect one might think it has). This question should be updated with relevant information, as already requested.